# NSIS invisible header text

Tags: nsis

Header text in license window is invisible. After I click I Agree button and Back button text appears.

```
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP "MY\IMAGE.bmp"
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP_NOSTRETCH
```

I use WelcomeFinish.nsi

How can I solve this?

Comment: NSIS version? Windows version? Did you modify WelcomeFinish.nsi?

Comment: @Anders NSIS v3.03, Windows 10. I only added three strings above with my path to bmp.

Comment: Works fine for me. Does http://nsis.sf.net/temp/WelcomeFinish.exe have the same problem?

Comment: @Anders Well, I guess this is some sort of magic and my PC is not worthy. I'll find proper PC to compile my scripts. Thank you for this revelation! :)

Comment: @Anders Tried to compile on another PC, same problem. Maybe something wrong with my bmp file? I just converted it with a program.

Comment: @Anders I want my image to cover the whole area of the header. But this image is above the text.

Comment: @Anders Looks like I need to change the order in which objects are created because when I set a background of text to transparent, installer starts to draw text over text.

Comment: It was never designed to support a image that covers the entire header IIRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to use Resource Hacker to change the order of elements on exe template.